# Docker, mount volumes as readonly

Tags: readonly, docker

I am working with Docker, and I want to mount a dynamic folder that changes a lot (so I would not have to make a Docker image for each execution, which would be too costly), but I want that folder to be read-only. Changing the folder owner to someone else works. However, `chown` requires `root` access, which I would prefer not to expose to an application.

When I use `-v` flag to mount, it gives whatever the username I give, I created a non-root user inside the docker image, however, all the files in the volume with the owner as the user that ran docker, changes into the user I give from the command line, so I cannot make read-only files and folders. How can I prevent this?

I also added `mustafa ALL=(docker) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker`, so I could change to another user via terminal, but still, the files have permissions for my user.

Comment: Just thought I'd leave a comment here saying that enabling a user to run docker containers it the same as giving him full root access. This is also documented in the security section of the docker documentation.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can specify that a volume should be read-only by appending `:ro` to the `-v` switch:

```sh
docker run -v volume-name:/path/in/container:ro my/image
```

Note that the folder is then read-only in the container and read-write on the host.

## 2018 Edit

According to the [Use volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume), there is now another way to mount volumes by using the `--mount` switch. Here is how to utilize that with read-only:

```sh
$ docker run --mount source=volume-name,destination=/path/in/container,readonly my/image
```

## docker-compose

Here is an example on how to specify read-only containers in `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    read_only: true
```

Comment: is there allow writes, but not write them back up to the host? that would be fantastic

Comment: That sounds like you want to specify no volume at all.

Comment: Sort of... I just dont like having to build an image just to make use of Dockerfile COPY or use a separate `docker cp` command on a shut off container.

Comment: Maybe you could create a new question for that where you provide more details and link it here?

Comment: You can also use the short syntax with docker compote, ie `redis:alpine:ro`

Comment: I'm using the `-v ...:ro` variant. I'd say it isn't the folder that becomes read-only, but the file system through which the container sees the folder. Permissions of the folder show it as writable, but write access fails with the message that the file system is read-only.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to `:ro` for devcontainers (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) ?

Answer (score 113):

## docker-compose

Here is a proper way to specify read-only volume in `docker-compose`:

#### Long syntax

```yaml
version: "3.2" # Use version 3.2 or above
services:
  my_service:
    image: my:image
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: volume-name
        target: /path/in/container
        read_only: true
volumes:
  volume-name:
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3

#### Short syntax

Add `:ro` to the volume mount definition:

```yaml
version: "3.0" # Use version 3.0 or above
services:
  my_service:
    image: my:image
    volumes:
      - /path/on/host:/path/inside/container:ro
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3

Comment: It is indeed proper, but what is read-only here is a volume, not a container.

Comment: This only works for me with `version: "3.2"` - Thanks :)

Comment: You can also do `- './my-file.txt:/container-readonly-file.txt:ro'` under `volumes` - note the `:ro` at the end.

Comment: Does this works with mysql database?

Comment: Yes, this works with any docker image