# Is a docker volume a 2 way connection

Tags: docker

```
docker -v host_dir:container_dir ...
```

I know from the above, when we're running scripts inside the container, writing to container_dir copies the written files to host_dir. But are all host_dir files also synced into the container?

Comment: Actually, the host directory is mounted in the container under the container directory name. So it is the same directory, nothing is copied or synced.

Answer (score -1):

By default it is mounted as rw (read-write mode) , Howver in case you need a readonly volume it is possible.

```
docker run -v volume-name:/path/in/container:ro my/image
```

In Docker-Compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    read_only: true
```

Take reference : [Docker, mount volumes as readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158810/docker-mount-volumes-as-readonly)