# Make all folders in Docker read-only EXCEPT

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a need to make all folders in the directory read only/read-only/readonly (via **volumes**) except one specific one

```
# All read-only
/opt/users_project:/opt/users_project:ro
# except myuser folder
/opt/users_project/myuser:/opt/users_project/myuser
```

How to do it?

P.S.: No, there is NO answer there ([Docker, mount volumes as readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158810/docker-mount-volumes-as-readonly))!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158810/docker-mount-volumes-as-readonly

Comment: @Mr. Unfortunately, I don't see an exception folder substitution form there(

Comment: What are in these directories?  Could you `COPY` the `users_project` directory in your Dockerfile, make it owned by root, but then switch `USER` to a non-root user?  That would in effect make the code read-only, and let you bind-mount a writeable data directory.

Comment: You seem to have already answered it in your question. Can you show the commands you've tried running and errors you are seeing. Make sure it's a [mcve].

Comment: No, there is NO answer there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158810/docker-mount-volumes-as-readonly)! 

Please remove the duplicate die from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bind-mount the directories with the desired settings:

```sh
docker run -v /opt/users_project/:/opt/users_project/:ro -v /opt/users_project/myuser/:/opt/users_project/myuser/:rw your_image
```

This will first bind-mount `/opt/users_project/` and all contained directories read-only into the container. *On top of that* `/opt/users_project/myuser/` is bind-mounted read-write allowing the container to change files in that directory *only*.

`docker` will automatically consider nested volumes and always mount the parent volumes first. With `docker-compose` it works analogously.